# iOS CoreAudio Producing Low Quality vs Comparable FFmpeg Function?

Tags: ios, audio, ffmpeg, core-audio, wav

In my iOS app, I'm converting an MP3 file to a 16-bit mono 22,050Hz WAV file. I'm defining the output as this:

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription outputFormat = new AudioStreamBasicDescription();
outputFormat.setFormat(AudioFormat.LinearPCM);
outputFormat.setFormatFlags(AudioFormatFlags.Canonical);
outputFormat.setBitsPerChannel(16);
outputFormat.setChannelsPerFrame(1);
outputFormat.setFramesPerPacket(1);
outputFormat.setBytesPerFrame(2);
outputFormat.setBytesPerPacket(2);
outputFormat.setSampleRate(22050);
```

In a different project, I'm using FFmpeg to accomplish the exact same thing with the exact same input - convert an MP3 file to a 16-bit mono 22,050Hz PCM (not WAV but close enough) file:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 22050
```

---

The file produced with FFmpeg sounds very similar if not identical to the MP3 file. **The file produced by iOS CoreAudio sounds noticeably low-quality, though.**

I'm wondering if there are some parameters or something I'm missing with my iOS setup?

Comment: Compare with afconvert?

Comment: If your MP3 is 44.1kHz, then CoreAudio is doing a sample rate conversion. I'm not sure what the quality of the default converter is, but perhaps it is much worse than ffmpeg.